# Angular 2 components scroll up on render

Tags: angular

When i scroll down a page and click a link to go to another component, i have to scroll to get to the top of new component.

Is this a known issue?

```
ngOnInit() {
   window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Yes, it is a known issue. See here for workaround: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6946 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7791